# I deployed a flask app on heroku , it was crashed immediately

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I deployed a flask application on heroku. At first the user interface opened but when using forms or buttons of the page, the server overloaded and the app crashed, although the app worked well locally.

the link of the app on github is -
    https://github.com/ahmedtoba/gas-lift

the link of the app is -
    https://gas-lift.herokuapp.com/

Comment: What did your logs say?

Comment: In addition to the log output that Unsolved Cypher is asking for, questions here should be self-contained. We shouldn't have to go off-site just to understand your question, and we _certainly_ shouldn't have to dig through your entire repository for answers. Please include the logs and any relevant code _directly in your question_. Ideally, you should provide a [mcve].